# My program crashes after i hold the w key to move the turtle for too long in the turtle library

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The code is as follows:

```
import turtle

width = 400
length = 300

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("x")

drawer = turtle.Turtle()
drawer.speed(3)
drawer.begin_fill()
drawer.color("blue", "yellow")

def drawern():
    drawer.seth(90)
    drawer.fd(1)

def drawerw():
    drawer.seth(180)
    drawer.fd(1)

def drawers():
    drawer.seth(270)
    drawer.fd(1)

def drawere():
    drawer.seth(0)
    drawer.fd(1)

wn.onkeypress(drawern, "w")
wn.onkeypress(drawerw, "a")
wn.onkeypress(drawers, "s")
wn.onkeypress(drawere, "d")

wn.listen()

wn.mainloop()
```

It gives a stack overflow error. Does anyone know why this issue persists? It doesn't happen when i let go of it once in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the stack overflow error is due to repeated assigning of angle to the stack. To prevent this, you can introduce a `debounce`. We will name our `debounce` as `move`.
A debounce, in simple terms, is fail-safe to prevent an event for triggering again and again while keeping the rest of the code running.

Define the variable in global space:

```py
move = False
```

As for the function:

```py
def drawern():
    global move #To let the function know the variable is from global scope

    if not move: #The key is pressed first time
        drawer.seth(90)
        move = True #Sets our debounce to True, it will not activate until the key is released
        
    drawer.fd(1)

wn.onkeypress(drawern, "w")
```

We need to have another function with an event to reset our debounce:

```py
def reset_db():
    global move
    move = False #Resets the debounce, referencing the key has been released

wn.onkeyrelease(reset_db, "w") #Connects the event
```

I have demonstrated for `w` key here only. You can duplicate it for the rest of the keys too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but after i applied your changes and set drawer.fd(1) to something higher like 10, the issue seems to persist once again. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 1667, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.ThreadTracer.__call__
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized` This is the crash report. Maybe it's something else that's causing it?

Comment: May I know after how much time the error came. Because as for me, I held it for more than a min, and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working again after i deleted the other functions and applied your fix to all the funs. Thanks for the help!